# Triggering action(s) upon ClientConnectionFactory connection establishment/acceptance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am currently using a `TcpNioClientConnectionFactory` to establish a TCP Connection to a desired host. I need to be able to perform some actions once connection establishment/acceptance has been made with that host. The actions I need to perform involve sending a message to the desired host so I need to know the connection has been accepted at the socket level before doing so.

I currently have a Spring `@EventListener` configured to catch all `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` events. However, it does not seem that this event is being published at the time when the outbound TCP connection has been accepted by the host. This was to be expected given the name of the event but I did find it interesting that the `connectionId` of the event being published contained a host value of 'unknown'.

I am wondering if there is anyway for me to catch the acceptance of the TCP Connection from the destination host similar to the `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` and trigger actions as I need? Ideally I would be able to capture this acceptance in such a way that I have a complete `connectionId` for the newly established connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug since 5.2.x (regression when we added support for connection timeout). The event is now published before the connection is established.

The fix will be in tomorrow's releases; [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291284/triggering-actions-upon-clientconnectionfactory-connection-establishment-accep).

Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks Gary that is good to hear. Glad a fix can be made and I see that fix has been committed to 5.2.x branch. Is there a schedule for 5.2.7 release?

Comment: As I said in my answer; it's [due today](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/milestone/35).